# How to store output of doctest in a junit xml format

Tags: pytest, doctest

How can the output generated from doctest in python be saved into a junit xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command from the directory where the doctest file is placed

python -m pytest -v --junitxml=./.xml